# is there an R function to determine how results of F-tests or likelihood ratio tests were constructed?

Tags: r, glm, lme4

when using glm or manyglm or lmer or similar, is there a function that permits one to determine how F-tests or likelihood ratio-tests were constructed. More specifically, a function that shows what was used as the denominator for individual tests.

Comment: The R CRAN package notes for each of those functions will describe how they are constructued.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. With complex ANOVA models representing both fixed and random factors (including nested factors) the divisor of some of the F-tests are not always the residual but may include higher-order random terms. I was hoping there was a function that showed the divisor for each F-test.